# boost.test Project template not available in VS2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost

VS2019 does not have a boost.test Projecttype available although I did the following steps:

- boost test adapter installed
- boost test package with vcpkg installed according to:
  https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/visualstudio/test/how-to-use-boost-test-for-cpp?view=vs-2019

VS Version:
Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2019
Version 16.10.3

OS:
W10 V1909

Comment: Boost.Test requires Boost. Whether you have installed the Boost?

Comment: Yes, I installed the boost Libraries, using vcpkg.exe as described in the Microsoft documentation